# Extract Column name and datatype from table in ssms with Powershell

Tags: powershell, ssms, extract

I'm trying to do an extract of the column name and datatype of a table in ssms with PowerShell.
I will like the output to be in three columns.

First column: The name of the Column in the table
Second column: The datatype of the column
Third column: tells if it keeps null values.

As an example:
[image]

I'm new to powershell and can't find the right way of doing this - Can Anyone help?

Tryed different apporaches and googled but can't find a solution.

Comment: Do you have to use Powershell to interact with SSMS? It would be much easier to query SQL Server directly from Powershell.

Comment: I will like to get the informations for other purpose - It is not for executing in ssms